# sts 4.7.0.RELEASE starts embedded mongo

Tags: spring-tools-4

Seems that the new release by default starts the Embedded Mongo when it's found on the classpath instead of using the mongo template defined in the application.properties.
The workaround is to temporary remove flapdoodle.embed from the dependency list even if it's in test scope

```
2020-06-24 09:22:53.048  INFO 51028 --- [     Thread-305] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2020-06-24T09:22:53.047+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=51029 port=63665 dbpath=/var/folders/7x/ss8w17pd4bsfrg1x1t56sl00zq753h/T/embedmongo-db-20d4fbe0-abac-4715-8ae0-b863f7bc9627 64-bit host=M84452
```

Comment: forgot to mention that it's when launching the app from boot dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/493.

The short version is that the behavior of the launch configs slightly changed due to the (now correct) usage of the "exclude test classes" checkbox of the Eclipse platform. Make sure that when you re-use existing launch configs that this checkbox is set correctly.